# SMTP email failing via Joomla, succeeding outside of Joomla

Tags: php, joomla-3.4

I think I need a way to debug in more detail how Joomla is trying to send SMTP email because I can't get any of its email mechanisms working, but I feel like SMTP is the one most likely to work since I've gotten SMTP email working on the same host with other test code. The error I am receiving when trying to send a private message from the primary super user account to another super user account using Components -> Messaging -> New Private Message is as follows:

```
Notice
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
```

My SMTP settings in the global configuration are as follows:

```
Send Mail: Yes
Mailer: SMTP
From email: bluemonkmn@sgdk2.enigmadream.com
From name: Benjamin Marty
Disable Mass Mail: No
SMTP Authentication: Yes
SMTP Security: None
SMTP Port: 25
SMTP Username: bluemonkmn@sgdk2.enigmadream.com
SMTP Password: (same password I used in the script below)
SMTP Host: mail.sgdk2.enigmadream.com
```

When the failure occurred, I decided to try a test using PHPMailer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and the following script recommended by Dreamhost at http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHPMailer:

```
<?php
/**
* This example shows making an SMTP connection with authentication.
*/

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP timezone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "mail.sgdk2.enigmadream.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "bluemonkmn@sgdk2.enigmadream.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "See Comment"; // I used the same password configured above
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('bluemonkmn@sgdk2.enigmadream.com', 'Benjamin Marty');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('bluemonkmn@sgdk2.enigmadream.com', 'Benjamin Marty');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('bluemonkmn@outlook.com', 'Ben Marty');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//if you want to include text in the body. 
$mail->Body    = "This is a test of email";

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

The PHP script was installed in a sub-directory of where I have Joomla installed, and it works just fine. But Joomla doesn't. How do I narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem was that Joomla uses the From address of the user sending the message instead of the From address configured in the global configuration's server settings. When I changed the super user's email address to match the addresses in my other test, then the email went through.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.. You beat me to it, I was just about to ask you what is the sender's email address, knowing that most of SMTP servers require that FromAddress and Username be the same...

Comment: @MirkoMikan This should be considered a Joomla bug, right? If the SMTP server settings have a From address, there should be a way to make sure that From address gets used, shouldn't there? Do you know where I could go next in determining whether this is a bug and reporting it? (The sender should be used in reply-to, not from, IMO.)

Comment: I wouldn't go that far in claiming that's a Joomla bug, In my eight years of working with her I would always think first as my lack of knowledge and experience, and never-ever thought I found her bug. But if you are certain its a bug you can always try http://docs.joomla.org/Filing_bugs_and_issues

Comment: I usually think that too, but this case is simple enough that, even though I have very limited experience with Joomla, my 20+ years of general programming experience is telling me that this is at least worth submitting for consideration as a bug. I've noticed at least in the software I write, there are too many problems that people just deal with instead of reporting. So it'll be interesting to see what happens with https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/9261

Comment: I will follow this Issue #9261 closely.